# 'at' Command not executing

Tags: macos, terminal, high-sierra

I have read the 'man atrun' page and ran the sudo command to enable `at`.

I did successfully create a scheduled job, but it does not execute the job at my scheduled time. I only have an `at.deny` and `cron.deny` file in `/var/at`. If I access `/var/at/jobs`, I can see the job I just created as an executable file. I then double-click the job and it then runs the job I scheduled in Terminal.

Do I need an `at.allow` file?

I am running High Sierra (10.13).

Comment: After I enabled atrun with the command mentioned in the manpage, I get periodic entries in the system log saying that atrun exited with status 1. If I run atrun manually (as root), it runs any pending jobs just fine. Does this match your experience? Maybe modify the launchd .plist file so that atrun gets passed the '-d' switch; judging by the source code, that should turn on some debugging output. I cannot test it at the moment as my High Sierra machine is turned off and far away...

Comment: Tried again some days later, and then it worked, and I have absolutely _no_ idea what I did differently. Oh well, at least it shows that it is not impossible... A friend reported it working on first attempt. I wonder what is going on here...

Comment: As of macOS 12.2.1, the best write-up I've seen to answer this is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478840/193772